# Save/retrieving data from firebase snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save the items a user has ordered and get the information on the other end, but when retrieving the data it seems to not be a dictionary anymore and I am not able to access the items from the order.

This is what I'm using to save the data

```
for (i,item) in currentOrder.enumerated().reversed(){

restaurantRef.child("order").child("dish\(i+1)").updateChildValues([
    "dishName": item.name,
    "dishPrice": item.price,
    "dishQuantity": item.quantity,
    "servWFood": item.servWithFood
    ])
```

}
this is a print() of what is being sent:

```
["dishName": "Baked Ricotta and Pancetta Tarts", "servWFood": false, "dishQuantity": 1, "dishPrice": 18.0]
["dishName": "Water", "servWFood": false, "dishQuantity": 1, "dishPrice": 10.0]
```

and this how the database looks after the data is sent:
[Database img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ydd.png)

and this what I'm using to retrieve the data:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Restaurants").child(restaurantUid).child("Tables")

ref.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in

if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
    
    if let orders = dictionary["order"] as? NSDictionary{
        
        for item in orders{
            print("item \(item)")
         
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the value of item is:

```
item (key: "dish3", value: {
    dishName = "Steak and Tomato Panzanella";
    dishPrice = 25;
    dishQuantity = 1;
    servWFood = 0;
})
```

and I would like to get each one of those 4 dish informations, but haven't been able to.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was just missing one level down after after getting to the items in the order.

```
                if let orders = dictionary["order"] as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for items in orders{

                    if let item = orders[items.key] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let dishName = item["dishName"] as? String
                        let dishPrice = item["dishPrice"] as? Double
                        let dishQuantity = item["dishQuantity"] as? Int
                        let servWFood = item["servWFood"] as? Bool

                        print("dishName \(dishName), dishPrice: \(dishPrice), dishQuantity: \(dishQuantity), servWFood: \(servWFood)")

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the orders for "RestTable1":

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Restaurants").child(restaurantUid).child("Tables").child("RestTable1").child("order")

ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let orderChildSnapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        for dish in orderChildSnapshots {
            print("dish: \(dish.key)")

            ref.child(dish.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (dishSnapshot) in
                if let dict = dishSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let name = dict["dishName"] as? String
                    let price = dict["dishPrice"] as? Int

                    print("dishName: \(name)")
                    print("dishPrice: \(price)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get them item in the same format. Print() output:
`item Snap (dish1) {
    dishName = "Pear, Brie and Prosciutto Wedges";
    dishPrice = 12;
    dishQuantity = 1;
    servWFood = 0;
}`